# How to smooth curve on mesh via python?

Tags: python

I have list `curve` of curvePoints on mesh, each curvePoint pt has a start point `pt.start` on one edge of a triangle, an end point `pt.end` on another edge of this triangle, `pt.p` is the mid point, `pt.start_eid` and `pt.end_eid` as the local edge id of the point on the face, and `pt.f` stores the face id of this triangle. `pt[i+1].start = pt[i].end`.

How can I remove the small kicks at the two ends of the curve and smooth out the curve via python?

Edit: For smoothing, I'm thinking of something like

```
curves_new=[]
for curve in curves:
   curve_new=[]
   curve_new.append(curve[0])
   for i in range[1,len(curve)-1]:
      pt_tmp = 0.5*(curve[i+1].p + curve[i-1].p) # mid point of new line segment
      # project pt_tmp to new face and edge.
      # do rest
```

But it requires a camera matrix to project `pt_tmp` to new face and edge, not sure if it can be computed or approximated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you provide a blend file with your current result? (I think it's difficult to answer that without the context you have)

Comment: it's hard to understand why you consider the leftmost circle not smooth and what would be the smooth result

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady The leftmost circle deviates drastically from the main direction of the curve.  The smooth result would be the one that removes the sections deviating from the main direction at both ends and averages out the wiggles in between.

Comment: You can use geonodes to blur the position and apply the tree using Python, or you can directly in Python blur the positions: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9471652/1149282